# Draw shapes of Hollow square and Triangle using string

Tags: c#

//I am getting error like "cannot draw the shape" on three occasions when functions are called
//What should be changed in if and for loops of square such that when height or width is less than one it should say "cannot draw the shape". 
you can see in the code that when in give height as 1 and width as 5 it is showing "cannot draw".

Here's my code in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ShapeDrawer {
    public static string DrawSquare(int height, int width) {
```

//code to draw the square here

```
        string s = "";
        string wrong = "Cannot draw that shape.";
```

//condition if width and height is less than 1 then should print cannot draw

```
    }if (width < 1 || height < 1) {
            return wrong;
        } else {
            //nested for loops to check the condition
            for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)  {
                for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++) {
                    if (i == 1 | j == 1 || i == height || j == width) {
                        if (width <= 1 || height <= 1) {
                            s = s + "Cannot draw that shape.";
                        } else {
                            //print asterisk if condition is true
                            s = s + "*";
                        }
                    } else {
                        s = s + " ";
                    }
                }
                s = s + "\n";
            }

            return s;
        }
```

//to print isosceles triangle

```
    public static string DrawIsoscelesTriangle(int size) {
        //code to draw the triangle
        string s = "";
        string wrong = "Cannot draw that shape.";

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                s = s + "*";
            }
            s = s + "\n";
        }
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 1; i--){
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
                s = s + "*";
            }
            s = s + "\n";
        }
```

//if size of the triangle less than 2 then print cannot draw

```
        if (size < 2) {
            return wrong;
        } else {
            return s;
        }
    }
}


class Program {
```

//main to call functions

```
    static void Main() {
```

//inputs for square with height and width

```
        Console.WriteLine(ShapeDrawer.DrawSquare(1, 5));
```

//inputs for square with size 2

```
        Console.WriteLine(ShapeDrawer.DrawIsoscelesTriangle(2));
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use debugger! In the square one, you explicitly set that you cannot draw `if (width <= 1 || height <= 1) {s = s + "Cannot draw that shape.";` and your square size is 1x5.

Comment: Yeah just realised that. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah just realized that. Thank you. But the condition for square is that it should print cannot draw that shape if height or width is less than one. even though when i give  height as 1, it is saying that cannot draw, can you explain?? thanks.

Comment: In drawSquare, width <= 1 || height <= 1 , is this deliberate ?

Comment: @PraneetNadkar well that's the condition which is wanted to print that it cannot be drawn.